# Radio buttons either side of JQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I've been playing around with the various layouts in JQM, trying to set up a list with radio buttons on both left and right on each list row. I would like it to look like a standard vertical list of JQM radio options, except with text in the centre and radio buttons on both left and right.

Unfortunately the approaches I've tried so far are not looking too impressive. This is the first approach, showing using a fieldset data-type="horizontal" :

```
<div data-role="content"> 
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l1"/>
            <label for="radio-l1" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">&nbsp;</span></label>


            <input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l4" />
            <label for="radio-l4" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">&nbsp;</span></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

However I can't get this to stretch the whole page, or put the text I need in the middle.

Here's the second approach using a JQM Listview:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>
      <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l1"/>
                    <label for="radio-l1" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">&nbsp;</span></label>
                </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">The description Text</div>
        <div class="ui-block-c">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l1"/>
                    <label for="radio-l1" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">&nbsp;</span></label>
                </fieldset>
        </div>
        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Problem with this approach is the spacing - there's way too much of it.

Any suggestions on the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance for any hints.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses so far. I guess what I'm looking for ideally is my first example, but with a space (ideally a button) in between the two radio buttons which forces the buttons to the far left and right of the page, with everything grouped together to give it a toolbar appearance:

```
<div data-role="content"> 
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l1"/>
            <label for="radio-l1" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">&nbsp;</span></label>

            <span data-role="button">How can I get this to stretch to the page width?</span>

            <input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l4" />
            <label for="radio-l4" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">&nbsp;</span></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

(Edit - one more update with a button inserted)

Comment: Don't quite understand what you want, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9LqeF/? or do you want theradios all the way left and right? where do you want the text?

Comment: what don't you do it with CSS?

Comment: You only need to reduce the width of block ui-block-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a super clean solution, but this might work for you:  **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9LqeF/3/)**

I am using some absolute positioning in CSS to achive the stretching of the middle button while keeping the radios at extreme left and right. You can play with the actual css values to make them work for your exact buttons:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="TheContainer">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-c" value="list" checked="checked" data-corners="none" />
    <label for="radio-choice-c">Left</label> 

    <a data-role="button" class="midButton" data-role="button" data-corners="false">stretch to the page width?</a> 

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-e" value="gallery" />
    <label for="radio-choice-e">Right</label>
</div>

.TheContainer {
    height: 20px;
}
.TheContainer .midButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 87px;
    right: 87px;
}
.TheContainer .ui-radio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.TheContainer .ui-radio:first-child {
    left: 0px;
}
.TheContainer .ui-radio:last-child {
    right: 0px;
}
```

UPDATED after comment to make LI less tall.

Comment: Almost exactly what I'm looking for - thank you. Only niggle would be the LI height being a bit big.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
                 <div data-role="content">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l1"/></td>
                <td><label for="radio-l1" id="desc-l1" ><span style="display: block;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">where is this</span></label></td>
                <td align="center"><span data-role="button" style="display:block; width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">How can I get this to stretch to the page width?</span></td>
                <td><label for="radio-l4" id="desc-l1"><span style="display: block;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check">what is this</span></label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="radioleast" id="radio-l4" style="float:right;" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sort of, but I'm looking to insert text or a button between the left/right radios. Have updated my original question above.